# Magento2 : Set Limitation for Logged in customer address on checkout page?

Tags: magento2.3, php-7

I want to set the limitation for count of address list on the checkout page.

can we restrict it or not, if yes then How to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341031/magento-2-remove-add-new-address-button-from-checkout-page-if-we-have-have-5-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file in your local theme from

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js
```

Modify the function ,

/** @inheritdoc */
        initChildren: function () {

```
    if(addressList().length > 0){
        this.createRendererComponent(addressList()[0],this); /* It always set the first shipping address. Change the logic as per your requirement */
    }
    else{
        _.each(addressList(), this.createRendererComponent, this);
    }

    return this;
},
```

To hide New Address button,

Copy the html template from

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html
```

To the local theme and comment the below code

```
<if args="!isFormInline">
            <button type="button"
                    class="action action-show-popup"
                    click="showFormPopUp"
                    visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
                 visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
                 render="shippingFormTemplate" />
        </if>
```

Comment: But I want to show the address count 5

Comment: You can do it via for loop change @ManoM

Comment: Inside the if condition :
var addressCount = (addressList().length <= 5) ? addressList().length :5;
                for(var i=0; i < addressCount; i++) {
                    this.createRendererComponent(addressList()[i], i);
                }

Comment: Is it correct   ?

Comment: I did not try for 5 but please check from your side. @ManoM

Comment: Ok, @Mayur. Thanks.

Comment: @ManoM you are most welcome.