# Magento 2 Remove "Add New Address Button" from checkout page if we have have 5 address on the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

I want to show only 5 shipping address on this page, followed this below link [Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove “New Address” button from billing/shipping address with module or theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252910/magento-2-checkout-remove-new-address-button-from-billing-shipping-address).
[image]

/app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
// this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);
            if (addressList().length <= 5) {
                    this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
                }
```

I've added mixin this way
/app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Vendor_Checkout/js/view/shipping': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify isNewAddressAdded() logic in shipping.js. The following code will help you.

```
if (addressList().length >= 5) {
    this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
}
```

**Update:**

```
if (addressList().length >= 5) {
            this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
        } else {
            this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);
        }
```

**[Update (2021-07-12)]**

Add following code snippet on shipping.js before initialize method:

```
isVisibleAddNewAddress:  ko.observable(true),
```

Now in initialize method add the following code:

```
var addressCount = parseInt(addressList().length);
if (addressCount >= 5) {
    this.isVisibleAddNewAddress(false);
}
```

Now open shipping.html add the following code:

```
<if args="isVisibleAddNewAddress()">
    <button type="button"
            class="action action-show-popup"
            click="showFormPopUp"
            visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
        <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
</if>
```

Clear your browser js cache.

Comment: Where I need to put this condition?

Comment: Create a mixin or copy shipping.js in your theme (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js), Add above condition in initialize method. E.x the following line: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js#L103

Comment: Should I removed the line which is already there "this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);" I keep the above code before this line but I can not found any change there?

Comment: Hi Sohel Thanks for your help after modified the logic still I'm getting the same response, Can you have a look once!                                                                                  // this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);
            if (addressList().length <= 5) {
                    this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
                }

Comment: Clear your static content and clear your browser JS cache

Comment: Hi Suhal, I've copy shipping.js On this path  "/app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js" and add the above lines which you suggested then also I'm getting 6 address on the Checkout even I want to show max 5 address.Customer can't add more then 5 address, Can you please help me on this

Comment: Which means you can add 6 addresses now instead of 5?

Comment: Yes Sohel, Still I can add more then 5 but I want to restrict if customer have max 5 address then "add new address" button should not be visible.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have tested on 2.4.2. Follow [Update (2021-07-12)] instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sohel :)